# after signing in with google data is not rendering and the pages get mixed up with each other

Tags: javascript, angular, google-signin

I have a login system with signin with google and facebook option.
after login with facebook, I am able to render the form of a perticular user while after login with google, I am not able to render the complete form of the user and strange thing is the pages get mixed up with each other as showing 
below.

[image]

while when I am logging in with facebook, it is behaving correctly below.
[image]

In both the cases,my logic is same. i.e., I am comparing id and then adding the id to the route. and then on the other component constructor, I am fetching the id from route and then populating the data. below my code snippet.

```js
declare const gapi: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  email = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]);
  credential = {};
  public auth2: any;
  hide = true;
  loading = false;
  users = [];
  pinId;
  userId;
  userName: string;

  constructor(
    private element: ElementRef,
    private router: Router,
    private fb: FacebookService,
    private dataService: DataService
  ) {
    console.log('Initializing Facebook');
    console.log('ElementRef: ', this.element);
    const initParams: InitParams = {
      appId: '559178811099356',
      xfbml: true,
      version: 'v2.8'
    };

    fb.init(initParams);
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('in view init');
    this.googleInit();
  }
   googleInit() {
console.log(document.getElementById('googleBtn'));
    gapi.load('auth2', () => {
      this.auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
        client_id:
          '13892768329-54kr4ssbku48jgctclu9b3o7q1h5k3ei.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
        scope: 'profile email'
      });
      this.attachSignin(document.getElementById('googleBtn'));
    });
  }
  public attachSignin(element) {
    console.log('attach')
    this.auth2.attachClickHandler(
      element,
      {},
      googleUser => {
        const profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        console.log('Token || ' + googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token);
        console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId());
        console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
        console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
        console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());
        this.userId = profile.getId();
      console.log(this.userId);
      this.dataService.getUsers().subscribe(data => {
          this.users = data;
          console.log(this.users);
          this.users.forEach(element => {
            console.log(element.ID, this.userId);
            if (element.ID === this.userId) {
              this.pinId = element.pinId;
              console.log(this.pinId);
              console.log("55555");
              this.router.navigate(["schedule/" + this.pinId]);
            }
          });
        }, error => {
          console.log('error');
        });
      },
      error => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2));
      }
    );
  }

  getErrorMessage() {
    return this.email.hasError('required')
      ? 'You must enter a value'
      : this.email.hasError('email') ? 'Not a valid email' : '';
  }

  loginWithFb() {
    this.fb
      .login()
      .then((res: LoginResponse) => {
        console.log('Logged in', res);
        this.userId = res.authResponse.userID;
        console.log(this.userId);
        this.dataService.getUsers().subscribe(
          data => {
            this.users = data;
            console.log(this.users);
            this.users.forEach(element => {
              console.log(element.userId, this.userId);
              if (element.userId === this.userId) {
                this.pinId = element.pinId;
                console.log(this.pinId);
                console.log('55555');

                this.router.navigate(['schedule/' + this.pinId]);
              }
            });
          },
          error => {
            console.log('error');
          }
        );
      })
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }


  private handleError(error) {
    console.error('Error processing action', error);
  }

  login() {
    this.loading = true;
    console.log(this.credential);
    if (
      (this.credential['userName'] === 'shekhar@hummingwave.com' &&
        this.credential['password'] === 'shekhar') ||
      (this.credential['userName'] === 'ramola@hummingwave.com' &&
        this.credential['password'] === 'ramola') ||
      (this.credential['userName'] === 'varun@hummingwave.com' &&
        this.credential['password'] === 'varun')
    ) {
      console.log('login successfull');
      this.dataService.getUsers().subscribe(
        data => {
          this.users = data;
          console.log(this.users);
          this.users.forEach(element => {
            console.log(element.userName, this.credential['userName']);
            if (element.userName === this.credential['userName']) {
              this.pinId = element.pinId;
              console.log(this.pinId);
              console.log('55555');
              this.router.navigate(['schedule/' + this.pinId]);
            }
          });
        },
        error => {
          console.log('error');
        }
      );
    } else if (
      this.credential['userName'] === ' ' &&
      this.credential['password'] === ' '
    ) {
      console.log('do nothing');
    } else {
      alert('username and password do not match');
    }
  }
}



//component where I am populating the form
export class ScheduleComponent implements OnInit {
@ViewChild('f') scheduleForm: NgForm;
selectedTime: '';
selectedDate: '';
confirmation: false;
  formData= {};
  users = [];
  timeOptions = [];
  dateOptions = [];
  pinId;
  hide = true;
  credential = {};
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private dataService: DataService
  ) {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.pinId = +params['id'];
      console.log(this.pinId);
    });
   this.dataService.getUsers().subscribe(data => {
       this.users = data;
       console.log(this.users);
       this.users.forEach(element => {
         console.log(element);
         if (element.pinId === this.pinId) {
           this.timeOptions = element.timeOptions;
           this.dateOptions = element.dateOptions;
           console.log(this.timeOptions, this.dateOptions);
         }
       });
     }, error => {
       console.log("error");
     });
  }


  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
this.formData = this.scheduleForm.value;
console.log(this.formData);
this.router.navigate(['confirmation']);
this.router.navigate(["schedule/" + this.pinId + "/confirmation"]);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `public attachSignin()` function, After `this.router.navigate(["schedule/" + this.pinId]);`
I'm reloading the page again by `location.reload();`
though it is solving my problem but it is still looking odd as those mixed pages will still come and go in a fraction of a second.